# Remove border of cells in openpyxl

Tags: excel, pandas, openpyxl

How can I remove all borders around cells filled with content in a worksheet using openpyxl? I exported a pandas dataframe to excel with "`df.to_excel()`" and would like to remove all borders with openpyxl (or perhaps pandas). You can see the borders in the screenshot below.
[image: screenshot]

I searched on stackoverflow, but this question doesn't exist yet. I don't know how I can apply removing borders to all cells filled with contents on the worksheet (without the need of specifying a specific cell range).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to go through https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html but I can't find the exact commands when looking through here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Openpyxl in its simplest form, loop each cell and set border to None.
e.g.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook


wb = load_workbook("foo.xlsx")
ws = wb['Sheet1']

for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        cell.border = None

wb.save('foo_out.xlsx')
```

This code example loops through all used cells in the sheet which will of course set border to None on cells that do not have a border set. You can restrict the range of iter_rows using max and min row/column to size the range if necessary, though if your frame is the size shown in the example there is probably no point.

Comment: Thank you, can you please add code on how to open a specific workbook and pertaining worksheet?

Comment: Thank you very much, I can't upvote because I have not enough reputation.

Comment: But this will still keep the default borders, and not create an all white sheet?

Comment: @Henri, Do you mean gridlines? because it would not be an  all white sheet unless gridlines are disabled and en/disabling gridlines is something different to borders. OR same situation if you added a white fill to the whole sheet, which again is a different option.

Comment: @moken Yes, I meant gridlines, sorry.